# How to move the div with value containing A,B,C,D... up or down

Tags: jquery

```html
<div style="width:450px;height:200px;border:0px solid red;overflow:auto;padding:0;text-align:left" id="items">
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>1. </span><span>A</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>2. </span><span>B</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>3. </span><span>C</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>4. </span><span>D</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>5. </span><span>E</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>6. </span><span>F</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>7. </span><span>G</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>8. </span><span>H</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>9. </span><span>I</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>10. </span><span>J</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>11. </span><span>K</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>12. </span><span>L</span>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;">
        <span>13. </span><span>N</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to shift span tag upwards or downwards using index containing A,B,C,D... without moving numbers span tag

Comment: plz add some more details!

Comment: Can you please explain why you need that?

Comment: <div style="width:450px;height:200px;border:0px solid red;overflow:auto;padding:0;text-align:left" id="items">
 <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;"><span>1. </span><span>A</span></div>
 <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;"><span>2. </span><span>B</span></div>
 <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;"><span>3. </span><span>C</span></div>
 <div style="padding:3px;border:1px solid green;width:399px;"><span>4. </span><span>D</span></div>
</div> This thing i want to move up or down select Alphabet span tag

Comment: Just as an aside, you should ***really*** look in to using an external stylesheet.

Comment: In which order you want to do that?

Comment: i just want to shift only the alphabet span tag up or down as numbers span tag will remain as is like 1. A,2. B,3. C,4. D so if we move alphabet D to second index it will display as 1.A,2. D,3. B,4.C...

Comment: you can reorder and *re-set* the numbers (1., 2., 3., etc...) dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
function moveUp(s)
{
    $("span:contains('"+s+"')").parent().insertBefore($("span:contains('"+s+"')").parent().prev());
    order();
}

function moveDown(s)
{
    $("span:contains('"+s+"')").parent().insertAfter($("span:contains('"+s+"')").parent().next());
    order();
}

function order()
{
    var i=1;
    $("div#items span:first-child").each(function(){
        $(this).html(i+". ");
        i++;
    });
}


$("document").ready(function(){
    moveUp("C");
    moveDown("A");
});
```

#### Before:

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D
```

#### After:

```
1. C
2. A
3. B
4. D
```